# How to make fzf respect `FZF_DEFAULT_COMMAND` when using it through `FZF_COMPLETION_TRIGGER`?

Tags: zsh, find

As stated in the [README](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf#environment-variables), fzf only honors `FZF_DEFAULT_COMMAND` when invoked directly, and there is a separate setting `FZF_CTRL_T_COMMAND`. However, when I type a file pattern followed by a completion trigger (by default "**"), fzf still resorts to the built-in `find` command.

Is there an option to change the program fzf searches with when invoked through the completion trigger?